# На странице поиска не переведён "not" при исключении метки

Tags: дефект, локализация, список-вопросов

[[дефект] -[локализация]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82+-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не вижу этой строки в традусёре, так что надо бы на MSE.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ done: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323511/260198

Comment: Можно еще там ссылку на русомету дать, чтоб замкнулось нормально